# SQL - alternative

Tags: sql

The below query gives me list of count values:

```
SELECT books.name as a, 
COUNT(library.staff)as b
FROM library, books  
WHERE library.staff = books.id
GROUP BY books.name;
```

How do i get the max value of output

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(library.staff) = MAX(...)`

Comment: Why don't you want to use `limit` - that will be the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without window functions or limit:

```
with data as (
  select books.name as a, 
         COUNT(library.staff) as b
  FROM library
    JOIN books ON library.staff = books.id
  GROUP BY books.name
) 
select *
from data
where b = (select max(b) from data);
```

But maybe you'll now add *another* requirement that says "no common table expressions":

```
select books.name as a, 
       count(library.staff) as b
from library l
  join books b on l.staff = b.id
group by b.name
having count(l.staff) = (select max(cnt) 
                         from (
                            select count(*) cnt
                            from library l
                              join books b on l.staff = b.id
                            group by b.name) t 
                         );
```

If `books.id` is a primary (or unique) key, the second statement can be slightly simplified using:

```
select l.name as a, 
       count(l.staff) as b
from library l
  join books ON l.staff = b.id
group by b.name
having count(l.staff) = (select max(cnt) 
                         from (
                             select count(*) cnt
                             from library l
                             group by l.staff) t 
                         );
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html)?

```sql
SELECT a, b
  FROM (
    SELECT books.name as a, 
           count(library.staff) as b
           row_number() OVER (ORDER BY count(library.staff) DESC) as rn
      FROM library, books  
     WHERE library.staff = books.id
     GROUP BY books.name
    ) s
 WHERE rn=1;
```

Comment: No Sorry. No LIMIT, FETCH, FIRST, SKIP or WINDOWS FUNCTIONS

Comment: @lel: you should have added **all** of your strange requirements to the question. If you just ask for "without limit" you will get answers like this.